# Sitecore 'Item could not be found from query string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I have site where I am trying to use page editor, and for the most part it works, except in certain workflow states. I'm not sure what the connection is, but anytime an item is created, and it is in draft mode, it cannot be page edited - I get a screen that goes to the root of the site. If I change the workflow state to the final workflow state, then it works fine. I'm not sure what the issue was, so I went to the 'draft' mode of the workflow, and checked the 'final state' checkbox, and then page editor worked! I'm not sure what the issue is - something with what we've implemented, I assume, because it works fine on a brand new sitecore solution.

The logs state that:

4860 17:15:15 ERROR Item could not be found from query string. [ID is "{40D668D8-4A60-44D8-B6FC-3FF6CBA0B3CC}".]

But the item is clearly there, and when switched to any workflow step which has 'final' checked, it works..

Comment: Does the user have workflow write access to the draft workflow state?

Comment: I'm logged in as admin - does that still matter?

Comment: But if I go and check 'Final' even in the Draft state, it works..

Comment: Do you have any enhancements to workflow or item display? e.g. the filterItem pipeline?

Comment: I did on my own workflow, but then I switched it to the 'Sample Workflow' - the one that comes with Sitecore - same issue...

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should submit to support, or a side-effect of another plugin or enhancement not described here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix - I took a wrong upgrade path, and as such the web.config was not correct. To resolve, I took a copy of a vanilla web.config from the revision that I had, and merged my changes into it, that fixed it.